# Unable to import database to server MySql MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to import database from localhost to server ( I have WordPress website ).
MySql localhost version - 5.7
MariaDB server version - 5.5.68
And I get an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '`` 0), PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE ) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARAC ``' at line 6
>  program 'mysql' finished with
> non-zero exit code: 1

Code part

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ej_wpmailsmtp_debug_events`;
CREATE TABLE `ej_wpmailsmtp_debug_events`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
  `initiator` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
  `event_type` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Comment: It seems that your ancient version does not support `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)`. Replace with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: And try to use the same brand and version of software on localhost as you use on the website, to avoid compatibility surprises like this. MariaDB is not MySQL. Don't assume they are compatible.

Comment: Time to update. MariaDB 5.5 eoled 2 years ago.